# Need to remove SOQL inside for loop

Tags: trigger, soql, for

Below is my code snippet.Need to remove SOQL from for loop.

```
for(Invoice_CU__c inv:Trigger.new){
List<Exchange_Rate__c> abc = [SELECT Exchange_Rate_to_Euro__c FROM Exchange_Rate__c where Exchange_Rate_to_Euro__c<> NULL and Exchange_Rate_to_Euro__c<> 0 and Currency_ISO_Code__c=:inv.CurrencyIsoCode and Exchange_Rate_Start_Date__c<=:inv.Invoice_Date__c ORDER by Exchange_Rate_Start_Date__c DESC LIMIT 1];
inv.Currency_Conversion_Rate__c = abc[0].Exchange_Rate_to_Euro__c;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code -

```
List<Exchange_Rate__c> abc = [SELECT Exchange_Rate_to_Euro__c 
                                   FROM Exchange_Rate__c 
                                   where Exchange_Rate_to_Euro__c<> NULL 
                                   and Exchange_Rate_to_Euro__c<> 0 
                                   ORDER by Exchange_Rate_Start_Date__c
                                 ];

Boolean limit1 = false;

for(Invoice_CU__c inv:Trigger.new){
    for(Exchange_Rate__c ExchangeRateRecord : abc ){
        if(limit1 == false && ExchangeRateRecord.Currency_ISO_Code__c == inv.Currency_ISO_Code__c && ExchangeRateRecord.Exchange_Rate_Start_Date__c <= inv.Invoice_Date__c){
                inv.Currency_Conversion_Rate__c = ExchangeRateRecord.Exchange_Rate_to_Euro__c;
                limit1 = true;
        }

    }

limit1 = false;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet to find the records you want will probably be by dynamic SOQL. However, full optimization will require that your Exchange_Rate__c table has both an Exchange_Rate_End_Date__c field, and that no values in the database overlap chronologically for the same currency.

From there, you can build your filters:

```
String[] filters = new String[0];
Time midnight = Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0);

for(Invoice_CU__c record: Trigger.new) {
    DateTime recordDate = DateTime.newInstance(record.Invoice_Date__c, midnight);
    String dateAsString = recordDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd');
    filters.add('Exchange_Rate_Start_Date__c <= '+dateAsString +' AND '+
                'Exchange_Rate_End_Date__c >= '+dateAsString +' AND '+
                'Currency_ISO_Code__c = \''+record.CurrencyIsoCode+'\'');
    // Note: String.escapeSingleQuotes not necessary in prior filter because
    // it is a restricted picklist. Normally, you should use this method.
}
```

Next, you can use a special variant of the "DateRange" class that I use to find arbitrary dates within a range in a map:

```
class DateRangeWithIso {
    Date startDate, endDate;
    String isoCode;
    DateRangeWithIso(Date first, Date last, string code) {
        startDate = first;
        endDate = last;
        isoCode = code;
    }
    DateRangeWithIso(Date firstAndLast, string code) {
        startDate = endDate = firstAndLast;
        isoCode = code;
    }
    public Boolean equals(Object rangeObj) {
        DateRangeWithIso other = (DateRangeWithIso)rangeObj;
        return other.isoCode == isoCode && 
            startDate <= other.endDate && endDate >= other.startDate;
    }
    public Integer hashCode() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The next step is to populate a Map with your DateRangeWithIso:

```
Map<DateRangeWithIso, Exchange_Rate__c> exchangeRates = 
    new Map<DateRangeWithIso, Exchange_Rate__c>();

for(Exchange_Rate__c record:(Exchange_Rate__c[])Database.query(
    'SELECT Exchange_Rate_to_Euro__c, '+
    'Exchange_Rate_Start_Date__c, Exchange_Rate_End_Date__c, '+
    'CurrencyIsoCode FROM Exchange_Rate__c '+
    'WHERE ('+String.join(filters, ') OR (')+')'
    )) {
    exchangeRates.put(
        new DateRangeWithIso(
            record.Exchange_Rate_Start_Date__c, 
            record.Exchange_Rate_End_Date__c, 
            record.CurrencyIsoCode), 
        record);
}
```

Finally, you can look up the result value by going through your list again:

```
for(Invoice_CU__c record: Trigger.new) {
    Exchange_Rate__c exrate = exchangeRates.get(
        new DateRangeWithIso(record.Invoice_Date__c, record.CurrencyIsoCode));
    if(exrate != null) {
        record.Currency_Conversion_Rate__c = exrate.Exchange_Rate_to_Euro__c;
    }
}
```